# How to create a typed toy language environment mapping usign GADT and Data.Map?

Tags: haskell

I'm playing with Haskell, the idea were to create a toy language with help of GADTs. Interpreters usually have an environment mapping that maps variables names to values.

I have basically two types in my toy language int and bool represented by `I 10` and `B True` for example.

The problem is that I can't  create a map that hold both of these, here is my code

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, RankNTypes #-}

module Foo where

import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Maybe

data Expr a where
  V :: Char -> Expr a
  B :: Bool -> Expr Bool
  I :: Int -> Expr Int
  If :: Expr Bool -> Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a

type Env a = M.Map Char (Expr a)

env = M.fromList [('x', B True), ('y', I 10)]
-- Error here                      ----^^^^
-- [typecheck -Wdeferred-type-errors] [E] • Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘Bool’
--   Expected type: Expr Bool
--     Actual type: Expr Int
-- • In the expression: I 10
--   In the expression: ('y', I 10)
--   In the first argument of ‘M.fromList’, namely
--     ‘[('x', B True), ('y', I 10)]’
```

How can I create such mapping?

Comment: Is there any reason you can’t just make each element an `Either (Expr Int) (Expr Bool)`? But if not, you can use existential types: `newtype SomeExpr = forall a. SomeExpr (Expr a)`, then make it a list of `SomeExpr`s.

Comment: Besides having only Int and Book in this case I would like to use more types in fufure, I will try the new type solution thanks

Comment: @ geckos That’s basically the same as @DanielWagner’s answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With such a small collection of types, I would use one of these:

```
type Env = Map Variable (Either (Expr Int) (Expr Bool))
type Env = (Map Variable (Expr Int), Map Variable (Expr Bool))
```

...depending on whether you want separate namespaces for each type or not. When there are more types available, then I would use one of these:

```
data UntypedExpr = forall a. UE (TypeRep a) (Expr a)
type Env = Map Variable UntypedExpr
-- OR
newtype SingleTypeEnv a = STE (Map Variable (Expr a))
type Env = TypeRepMap SingleTypeEnv
```

...again depending on whether you want a separate namespace for each type or not.

`TypeRep` is from the base package (or you could make up some new GADT that's more specific to your EDSL's types), and `TypeRepMap` is from [typerep-map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/typerep-map).

Comment: Curious to know why you need a `TypeRep` in an `UntypedExpr`? Surely `forall a. UE (Expr a)` would be sufficient.

Comment: @bradrn Sufficient for what, exactly?

Comment: Somehow I have the feeling `DMap` might come up when being fancier, but I don't know enough about this.

Comment: @DanielWagner Sufficient for any use I can think of, I guess

Comment: @bradrn I dunno, I think it's pretty reasonable to suppose one might want to have access to the type dynamically, without re-traversing the expression to rediscover it. For example, one might want to print a type error.

Comment: @DanielWagner I suppose so… I just think it’s a bit redundant, given that you can always recover the `TypeRep` with `typeOf undefined :: Typeable a => TypeRep a` plus -XScopedTypeVariables.

Comment: @dfeuer `DMap` would be a fine alternative to the `SingleTypeEnv` approach, yes.

Comment: @bradrn No, I don't think you can. Have you tried writing this function, which takes in an `UntypedExpr` with no `TypeRep`, and produces a `TypeRep` (or prints one or something, to avoid the annoying question of what type to give such a function)? I think you'll find you must write a recursive function which traverses the `Expr` inside.

Comment: @DanielWagner Um, no, I haven’t… perhaps I should before I say these things!

Comment: @DanielWagner, I think your variables have to be typed (and offer type evidence?) to use a `DMap`. Like I said, I don't really know how this stuff works in practice.

Comment: @dfeuer Yep. And it's easy to go back and forth between "I have enough information about the variable statically to make a `TypeRep` to serve as the key in a `TypeRepMap`" and "I have enough information about the variable statically to make a typed key for a `DMap`".

Comment: @DanielWagner Turns out `recover (UE (_ :: Expr a)) = show $ typeOf (Proxy @a)` works correctly, but only if you define it as `data UntypedExpr = forall a. Typeable a => UE (Expr a)` with a `Typeable` constraint.

Comment: @bradrn Sure. Storing a witness of the `Typeable` constraint (which is what your `forall a. Typeable a =>` says to do) and explicitly storing a `TypeRep` are isomorphic.

Comment: @DanielWagner OK, this is a good point. I personally prefer the constraint, but it’s really a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @DanielWagner thanks for the help if I try the UntypeExpr line it gives me this error: `[typecheck] [E] • Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘TypeRep’ has kind ‘*’
`. Am I missing an extension? I have GADTs and RankNTypes enabled. Typeable is new to me

Comment: This `data UntypeExpr = forall a. UE TypeRep (Expr a)` works fine

Comment: @geckos You're using the bad old `TypeRep` from `Data.Typeable`. You want the [new and improved `TypeRep`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Type-Reflection.html#t:TypeRep) from `Type.Reflection`.

Comment: What is the intuition behind TypeRep? It holds a representation of a type? I could instantiate `UntypedExpr` like this `Ue (typeRep @Int) (I 10)` for example. So I need to apply the types explicitly so it can carry the type for me!?

Comment: @geckos Yes, a `TypeRep a` is a runtime representation of the type `a`. (Types are otherwise unavailable -- you may have heard the term "erased" -- at runtime in Haskell.) You should not need the type application, if you use `Type.Reflection` as I advise. Just `UE typeRep (I 10)` should be sufficient.